# How do I set up a Mac to use both FileVault and Boot Camp?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, filevault

I understand FileVault will encrypt the volume Mac OS X is installed on. I guess this means that Windows won't be able to read it.

How can I set up a MacBook to use FileVault for the Mac OS X partition and still use Boot Camp? Can I explain to the Boot Camp software that I want a third partition accessible to both systems?

Can I use Microsoft's disk encryption for the Windows partition at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use Bootcamp with the new Filevault.  The exact method of achieving this may differ depending on if you already have Filevault turned on, and want to install bootcamp, or if you already have bootcamp, and want to turn on Filevault...

Either way, you will need to ensure that you use the very latest bootcamp drivers package (4.0), which either need applying to your existing windows install or writing to CD/USB stick prior to beginning the bootcamp installer.

To check your current BootCamp level, run Boot Camp Assistant and select About from the menu bar, at the present time the current version is Version 4.0.1 (429).

Comment: What are the exact methods for the two cases?

Comment: Depends on where you are at - Have you got either setup already?

Comment: I can start either way. I'd buy a new Mac for this.

Comment: In that case, I would start with Bootcamp.  Filevault encrypts your whole MAC partition, not the drive, but your Mac partition will *be* the whole drive by default.  So you would be wasting time encrypting something that you would need to unencrypted to partition for Bootcamp.  So, Bootcamp first, ensure you download the latest V4 driver package (it will prompt you), and then when your dual booting is working, turn on Filevault.  Without V4 bootcamp drivers, when Windows boots and sees the encrypted Mac partition, it will spit feathers and die.  I can't comment on Subsequent Win encryption.

Comment: How can I find out if I have Boot Camp 4? I installed Boot Camp a few weeks ago and it downloaded a new version. However, it downloaded the wrong language and hence I'm not sure if it got the version right.

Comment: Any idea if I can use Bitlocker on the Windows side?

Comment: I added some info in the answer for the BC version.  As for Bitlocker, I am not sure, although in theory is seems plausible.  I think the clincher is that Bitlockers seems to require 2 ntfs drives in order to work, and this will require manual partitioning of your drive without getting the bootcamp assistant to do it for you

Comment: Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: AppleControlPanel.exe
  Application Version: 4.0.0.2

Comment: Apparently it is version 4.0. Problem is, I cannot start the Boot Camp control panel, probably because it's the German version running on an English Windows 7. Any idea where I can download Boot Camp in English?

Comment: I have bootcamp version 6. But trying to enable filevault now gives the following error. 
""Some disk formats don’t support the recovery partition required by encryption. To use encryption, reinstall this version of OS X on a reformatted disk.""
I believe filevault is talking about bootcamp.

How do I get around this problem?