# FileVault 2 Boot camp Partition

Tags: macos, bootcamp, partition, high-sierra, filevault

I have seen several different answers to this question and so I am a bit confused.

If I enable Filevault 2 upon setup of my 2016 Macbook pro and THEN create a windows partition for boot camp, is the windows partition still covered by FileVault 2?

If someone was, for example to use MacQuisition. Would they need the Encryption password in order to access the windows partition as they would for the OS partition?

Here it says if you enable FileVault and then partition for windows, both partitions will be encrypted: [Can I enable FileVault and then partition my hard drive later?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/223431/can-i-enable-filevault-and-then-partition-my-hard-drive-later)

Here it says it is possible, but doesn't expand as to how:
[How do I set up a Mac to use both FileVault and Boot Camp?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39699/how-do-i-set-up-a-mac-to-use-both-filevault-and-boot-camp?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Here it says it will only encrypt the MacOS partition:
https://rc.partners.org/kb/article/2618

Thanks